# neo4j - how to re-run updated index on existing data?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have the following BaseContent class with a compound index:

```
public abstract class BaseContent<D extends BaseContentDTO> extends BaseEntity {

    /* The FULLTEXT index allows to search on non case-sensitive queries */
    @Indexed(indexName = "search_content")
    @NotNull
    protected String name;

    @Indexed(indexName = "search_content")
    protected Integer year;
}
```

Now, I need to update the index to be a FULLTEXT index in order to support non case sensitive search.

I modified it like this:

```
public abstract class BaseContent<D extends BaseContentDTO> extends BaseEntity {

    /* The FULLTEXT index allows to search on non case-sensitive queries */
    @Indexed(indexName = "search_content", indexType=IndexType.FULLTEXT)
    @NotNull
    protected String name;

    @Indexed(indexName = "search_content", indexType=IndexType.FULLTEXT)
    protected Integer year;
}
```

Now, when trying to raise the server I get exception:

```
Index with the same name but different config exists!
```

I manually deleted the previous index and when raising the server again, it seems that it created the indexes correctly.

However, when querying the existing data, I got the exception again and I realized that it didn't re-indexed the existing data again.

Is there a way to do re-index the existing data?

Thanks
Carmel

Comment: I would probably iterate over the entities again and re-set the properties and save them to reindex the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *add*  method of the *Index* class to add nodes to an existing index, like in the following code fragment:

```
   @Autowired Neo4jOperations neo4jOperations;
   Index index = neo4jOperations.getGraphDatabase().getIndex("search_content");
   Collection<YourClass> objects = neo4jOperations.findAll(YourClass.class).as(Collection.class);

   for (YourClass object: objects) {
        Node node = neo4jOperations.getNode(object.getId());

        index.add(node, "name", node.getProperty("name"));
        index.add(node, "year", node.getProperty("year"));
    }
```

I used the placeholder class name *YourClass* since you don't show the concrete class name in your code.